# React Navigation(version 4.x): Transition to the same screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am using `createStackNavigator`.  I have three screens: A, B, and C

Screen B is used **twice** during my transition. I use this notation:

`B(1)`: The first time we transit to screen B with some parameters

`B(2)`: The second time we transit to screen B with **different** parameters

Consider this transition:

`A --> B(1) --> C --> B(2)`

*Current behavior*:

When I transit from screen `A` to `B(1)`, `B(1)` to `C`, each time the new screen appears with an animation from **right to left**. But when I transit from `C` to `B(2)`, the new screen appears from **left to right**. (issue 1)

When I am on `B(2)` and use `navigation.goBack()`, I see `A` (but I want to see `C` of course)
(issue 2)

*Expected Behaviour*:

when I transit from `C` to `B(2)`, the new screen must appear  from **right to left** (Like previous transitions)

When I am on `B(2)` and use `navigation.goBack()`, I must see `C`

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.3
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz
    Memory: 246.99 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.13.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node
    npm: 6.12.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 28, 29
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2
      System Images: android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
    Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.7",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
```

Comment: Please add your navigation code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix "when I transit from C to B(2), the new screen must appear from right to left (Like previous transitions)" in screen C use this code to navigate :

```js
// this pushes B into the stack insted of navigating to B
() => navigation.push('B')
```

This "When I am on B(2) and use navigation.goBack(), I must see C" will be already fixed because the stack order is correct using push insted of navigate.
So your stack preview screen will be C.